# Convert Key-Value Pair String to .NET Object

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, deserialization

I have a json string like so (there are many properties but just including few values): `[{"Key":"ID","Value":"123"},{"Key":"Status","Value":"New"},{"Key":"Team","Value":"South"}]`

I have a class representing the values

```
    public class CustomObject
        {
            public string ID { get; set; }
            public string Status { get; set; }
            public string Team { get; set; }
//Other props

        }
```

So even though the JSON is an array of these objects containing `Key:x, Value:y`, the whole structure is really just an instance of my `CustomObject` class. This is the way the json is given to me. How can I convert this to a type of `CustomObject`?

Comment: The "Status" prop doesn't seem to be used in the second object, I see "Key" is set to "Status", are you sure "Status" is being used?

Comment: @OttoCheley Every property is being used. I'm sorry, I don't understand if that matters either way though? I still would need to access the value regardless.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. Create a new class that deserializes the JSON you get to a class of KeyValue pairs. Then take the values from this class based on the Keys you are interested in.

```
public class CustomObject
{
    public CustomObject() { }

    public CustomObject(List<KeyValueClass> jsonObject) // Use of Reflection here
    {
        foreach (var prop in typeof(CustomObject).GetProperties())
        {
            prop.SetValue(this, jsonObject.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key.Equals(prop.Name))?.Value, null);
        }
    }

    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Team { get; set; }

}

public class KeyValueClass
{
    [JsonProperty("Key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

and following is how you'd deserialize it.

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValueClass>>(json);
var customObj = new CustomObject()
{
    ID = obj.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key.Equals("ID"))?.Value,
    Status = obj.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key.Equals("Status"))?.Value,
    Team = obj.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key.Equals("Team"))?.Value
};

var customObj2 = new CustomObject(obj); // Using constructor to build your object.
```

Note: Based on convention, you should use UpperCase first letter for the variable names in the class. Use of JsonProperty helps in conforming to that standard.

Comment: this answer is good because for the `CustomObject` you can choose which values you want from the json. I hope you can see how this might be a little tedious if there are many properties in `CustomObject`. Is there a more stream-lined way?

Comment: @Bmoe added a constructor in the CustomObject class that uses Reflection to update all properties that may or may not exist in the json .. see my updated response above